How to inject numbers into heading elements
I made a JavaScript plugin that made headings into documentation style (also known as hierarchical numbered outlines or multilevel numbered outlines).
You often see these styles in legal documents, technical manuals. For example:
1. Main title
1.1. Sub-title
1.1.1. Sub-sub-title

I've now found some time to refactor and actually make the plugin work and robust. But I'm really having issue with injecting and incrementing the numbers.
This is the current code I have:
const scopeHeadingElements = scope.querySelectorAll(levelsRange);
const currentNumbers = {
  h1: headingNumbers.h1,
  h2: headingNumbers.h2,
  h3: headingNumbers.h3,
  h4: headingNumbers.h4,
  h5: headingNumbers.h5,
  h6: headingNumbers.h6
};
scopeHeadingElements.forEach((heading) => {
  const tagName = heading.tagName;
  const headingLevel = parseInt(tagName.substring(1));
  let numberText = '';
  currentNumbers['h' + (headingLevel + 1)]++;
  for (var levelNumber = 1; levelNumber <= 6; levelNumber++) {
    if(levelNumber <= headingLevel) {
      numberText += currentNumbers['h' + levelNumber] + options.separator;
    } else {
      continue;
    }
  }
  heading.innerHTML = `${numberText} ${heading.innerHTML}`;
});

The scopeHeadingElements returns any of the H1-H6 elements in the DOM depending on what the levelRange is. For example, it could be all H1 to H6 elements, or it could be scoped to H3-H4 elements.
The headingNumbers is the starting value of the heading documentation. For example, the page might start with: {h1: 1, h2: 1, h3: 1, h4: 1, h5: 1, h6: 1}
But if we are splitting documentation over multiple pages, we might want to start page two at: {h1: 12, h2: 1, h3: 5, h4: 8, h5: 1, h6: 10}
What I need this code to do in the loop over the scopeHeadingElements is to be able to prepend the documentation numbering to the innerHTML.

For example, if we have the starting headingNumbers: {h1: 1, h2: 1, h3: 1, h4: 1, h5: 1, h6: 1} then the following HTML scope should output the following:
<h1>Heading 1</h1> ----> <h1>1. Heading 1</h1>
<h2>Heading 2</h2> ----> <h2>1.1. Heading 2</h2>
<h3>Heading 3</h3> ----> <h3>1.1.1. Heading 3</h3>
<h4>Heading 4</h4> ----> <h4>1.1.1.1. Heading 4</h4>
<h5>Heading 5</h5> ----> <h5>1.1.1.1.1. Heading 5</h5>
<h6>Heading 6</h6> ----> <h6>1.1.1.1.1.1. Heading 6</h6>

However if the starting headingNumbers were different: {h1: 12, h2: 1, h3: 5, h4: 8, h5: 1, h6: 10} then the following HTML scope should output the following:
<h1>Heading 1</h1> ----> <h1>12. Heading 1</h1>
<h2>Heading 2</h2> ----> <h2>12.1. Heading 2</h2>
<h3>Heading 3</h3> ----> <h3>12.1.5. Heading 3</h3>
<h4>Heading 4</h4> ----> <h4>12.1.5.8. Heading 4</h4>
<h5>Heading 5</h5> ----> <h5>12.1.5.8.1. Heading 5</h5>
<h6>Heading 6</h6> ----> <h6>12.1.5.8.1.10. Heading 6</h6>

What is most important in all this though, is once the currently processed tag is higher than the existing one then we need to reset that value to 1.
So again the example of {h1: 1, h2: 1, h3: 1, h4: 1, h5: 1, h6: 1} then the following HTML scope should output the following:
<h1>Heading 1</h1> ----> <h1>1. Heading 1</h1>
<h2>Heading 2</h2> ----> <h2>1.1. Heading 2</h2>
<h2>Heading 2</h2> ----> <h2>1.2. Heading 2</h2>
<h3>Heading 3</h3> ----> <h3>1.2.1. Heading 3</h3>
<h3>Heading 3</h3> ----> <h3>1.2.2. Heading 3</h3>
<h4>Heading 4</h4> ----> <h4>1.2.2.1. Heading 4</h4>
<h2>Heading 2</h2> ----> <h2>1.3. Heading 2</h2>
<h3>Heading 3</h3> ----> <h3>1.3.1. Heading 3</h3>
<h4>Heading 4</h4> ----> <h4>1.3.1.1. Heading 4</h4>
<h5>Heading 5</h5> ----> <h5>1.3.1.1.1. Heading 5</h5>
<h6>Heading 6</h6> ----> <h6>1.3.1.1.1.1. Heading 6</h6>
<h6>Heading 6</h6> ----> <h6>1.3.1.1.1.2. Heading 6</h6>

In my above JS code, I just cannot seem to figure out how to get the looping, and incrementing working without it incrementing the wrong heading tag (some attempts increment the H1 value as well as the H2, or the H1, H2, and H3 value when incremeting the H4).
Or other attempts increment too early, and everything starts 1 off.
I tried to add a - 1 to the currentNumbers however if the levelsRange in const scopeHeadingElements = scope.querySelectorAll(levelsRange); is only matching on say, H2 to H4, then the other numbers go negative or to 0.
Essentially, all headings should be given the documentation numbering system, but if they arent included in the "scope" then the HTML isnt affected.
For example, if we had the example again of {h1: 1, h2: 1, h3: 1, h4: 1, h5: 1, h6: 1}, but for this the scope was limited to H2 to H3 elements:
<h1>Heading 1</h1> ----> <h1>Heading 1</h1>
<h2>Heading 2</h2> ----> <h2>1.1. Heading 2</h2>
<h2>Heading 2</h2> ----> <h2>1.2. Heading 2</h2>
<h3>Heading 3</h3> ----> <h3>1.2.1. Heading 3</h3>
<h3>Heading 3</h3> ----> <h3>1.2.2. Heading 3</h3>
<h4>Heading 4</h4> ----> <h4>Heading 4</h4>
<h2>Heading 2</h2> ----> <h2>1.3. Heading 2</h2>
<h3>Heading 3</h3> ----> <h3>1.3.1. Heading 3</h3>
<h4>Heading 4</h4> ----> <h4>Heading 4</h4>
<h5>Heading 5</h5> ----> <h5>Heading 5</h5>
<h6>Heading 6</h6> ----> <h6>Heading 6</h6>
<h6>Heading 6</h6> ----> <h6>Heading 6</h6>


Does a "CSS-only" approach count as well?
The next provided solution creates/ensures the correct numbering by css generated content, utilizing the ::before pseudo-element and its accompanying content property where counter-values are written via the counter() CSS function. And regarding the correct counting, there are heading and counter specific rules which either do create/reset or increment the targeted counters.


h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  margin: 4px 0;
}
body {
  margin: 0;

  counter-reset: h1 h2 h3 h4 h5 h6;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 1.6em;

  counter-reset: h2 h3 h4 h5 h6;
  counter-increment: h1;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 1.4em;

  counter-reset: h3 h4 h5 h6;
  counter-increment: h2;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 1.25em;

  counter-reset: h4 h5 h6;
  counter-increment: h3;
}
h4 {
  font-size: 1.1em;

  counter-reset: h5 h6;
  counter-increment: h4;
}
h5 {
  font-size: 1em;

  counter-reset: h6;
  counter-increment: h5;
}
h6 {
  font-size: .9em;

  counter-increment: h6;
}

h1::before { content: counter(h1) ". "; }
h2::before { content: counter(h1) "." counter(h2) ". "; }
h3::before { content: counter(h1) "." counter(h2) "." counter(h3) ". "; }
h4::before { content: counter(h1) "." counter(h2) "." counter(h3) "." counter(h4) ". "; }
h5::before { content: counter(h1) "." counter(h2) "." counter(h3) "." counter(h4) "." counter(h5) ". "; }
h6::before { content: counter(h1) "." counter(h2) "." counter(h3) "." counter(h4) "." counter(h5) "." counter(h6) ". "; }
<h1>Heading-1</h1>

  <h2>Heading-2</h2>

    <h3>Heading-3</h3>
    <h3>Heading-3</h3>
    
      <h4>Heading-4</h4>
      <h4>Heading-4</h4>

  <h2>Heading-2</h2>

    <h3>Heading-3</h3>
    <h3>Heading-3</h3>

      <h4>Heading-4</h4>

  <h2>Heading-2</h2>

    <h3>Heading-3</h3>

      <h4>Heading-4</h4>

        <h5>Heading-5</h5>

          <h6>Heading-6</h6>
          <h6>Heading-6</h6>


<h1>Heading-1</h1>

  <h2>Heading-2</h2>
  <h2>Heading-2</h2>

    <h3>Heading-3</h3>
    <h3>Heading-3</h3>

      <h4>Heading-4</h4>

  <h2>Heading-2</h2>

    <h3>Heading-3</h3>

      <h4>Heading-4</h4>

        <h5>Heading-5</h5>

          <h6>Heading-6</h6>
          <h6>Heading-6</h6>


<h1>Heading-1</h1>



And which heading-hierarchy's counter is (not) going to be displayed can be steered by additional excluding css rules, based on e.g. chained class selectors ... for instance as follows ...


h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  margin: 4px 0;
}
body {
  margin: 0;

  /* counter-reset: h1 h2 h3 h4 h5 h6; */
}
section {
  margin: 0 0 16px 0;
  border: 1px dashed black;

  counter-reset: h1 h2 h3 h4 h5 h6;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 1.6em;

  counter-reset: h2 h3 h4 h5 h6;
  counter-increment: h1;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 1.4em;

  counter-reset: h3 h4 h5 h6;
  counter-increment: h2;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 1.25em;

  counter-reset: h4 h5 h6;
  counter-increment: h3;
}
h4 {
  font-size: 1.1em;

  counter-reset: h5 h6;
  counter-increment: h4;
}
h5 {
  font-size: 1em;

  counter-reset: h6;
  counter-increment: h5;
}
h6 {
  font-size: .9em;

  counter-increment: h6;
}

h1::before { content: counter(h1) ". "; }
h2::before { content: counter(h1) "." counter(h2) ". "; }
h3::before { content: counter(h1) "." counter(h2) "." counter(h3) ". "; }
h4::before { content: counter(h1) "." counter(h2) "." counter(h3) "." counter(h4) ". "; }
h5::before { content: counter(h1) "." counter(h2) "." counter(h3) "." counter(h4) "." counter(h5) ". "; }
h6::before { content: counter(h1) "." counter(h2) "." counter(h3) "." counter(h4) "." counter(h5) "." counter(h6) ". "; }

.heading-count-not-for {
  &.h1 { h1::before { content: ""; } }
  &.h2 { h2::before { content: ""; } }
  &.h3 { h3::before { content: ""; } }
  &.h4 { h4::before { content: ""; } }
  &.h5 { h5::before { content: ""; } }
  &.h6 { h6::before { content: ""; } }
}
<section class="heading-count-not-for h4 h5 h6">
  <h1>Heading-1</h1>

    <h2>Heading-2</h2>

      <h3>Heading-3</h3>
      <h3>Heading-3</h3>

        <h4>Heading-4</h4>
        <h4>Heading-4</h4>

    <h2>Heading-2</h2>

      <h3>Heading-3</h3>
      <h3>Heading-3</h3>

        <h4>Heading-4</h4>

    <h2>Heading-2</h2>

      <h3>Heading-3</h3>

        <h4>Heading-4</h4>

          <h5>Heading-5</h5>

            <h6>Heading-6</h6>
            <h6>Heading-6</h6>


  <h1>Heading-1</h1>

    <h2>Heading-2</h2>
    <h2>Heading-2</h2>

      <h3>Heading-3</h3>
      <h3>Heading-3</h3>

        <h4>Heading-4</h4>

    <h2>Heading-2</h2>

      <h3>Heading-3</h3>

        <h4>Heading-4</h4>

          <h5>Heading-5</h5>

            <h6>Heading-6</h6>
            <h6>Heading-6</h6>


  <h1>Heading-1</h1>
</section>

<section class="heading-count-not-for h1 h3 h4 h5 h6">
  <h1>Heading-1</h1>

    <h2>Heading-2</h2>

      <h3>Heading-3</h3>
      <h3>Heading-3</h3>

        <h4>Heading-4</h4>
        <h4>Heading-4</h4>

    <h2>Heading-2</h2>

      <h3>Heading-3</h3>
      <h3>Heading-3</h3>

        <h4>Heading-4</h4>

    <h2>Heading-2</h2>

      <h3>Heading-3</h3>

        <h4>Heading-4</h4>

          <h5>Heading-5</h5>

            <h6>Heading-6</h6>
            <h6>Heading-6</h6>
</section>





Edit in order to provide a JS based solution as originally requested by the OP.
... quoting the OP's comment from my above provided "CSS-only" answer/s ...

Hi @Peter Seliger! Thanks for that code, and though it works amazingly as a CSS solution, this JS code will be part of a bigger JS first product, so on compile time it will statically be embedded into the DOM. If you have a JS only version of yours I'd love to see it! – markb

The next provided implementation comes with 3 different code-examples, each covering another of the OP's scenarios/use cases.
The implementation itself does mimic the behavior of the formerly provided "CSS-only" code-examples with their heading-counter specific rules, especially regarding their usage of counter-reset and counter-increment.
Regardless of the custom provided (maintained) heading-scopes, one always has to keep track of every heading-specific current counter-value. But in order to just display the scoped ones this solution does compute and assign counter-values exclusively for and to heading-elements which are tagged/configured as being in scope.
The latter is done by assigning the computed value to such an element's dataset.counter property which will immediately alter the very element's custom data-counter attribute-value with the latter being placed ::before its related heading-element by a single generic css-rule.
1st example code
The OP's usage of ...

custom configured different/varying heading-scopes
but default expected counter base-values of 1 ...



// begin ... counting-implementation or counting-module.

function createCountContextObjects(config) {
  const headingDefault = {
    counter: 1,
    inScope: true,
  };
  const { h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 } = (config || {});

  const configEntries = Object
    .entries({
      h1: { ...headingDefault, ...(h1 || {}) },
      h2: { ...headingDefault, ...(h2 || {}) },
      h3: { ...headingDefault, ...(h3 || {}) },
      h4: { ...headingDefault, ...(h4 || {}) },
      h5: { ...headingDefault, ...(h5 || {}) },
      h6: { ...headingDefault, ...(h6 || {}) },
    });

  const currentCounts = new Map(
    configEntries
      .map(([key, { counter }]) => {

        counter = parseInt(counter, 10);
        counter = Number.isFinite(counter) ? (counter - 1) : 0;

        return [key, { reset: counter, current: counter }]
      })
  );
  const scopedTagNames = new Set(
    configEntries 
      .filter(([_, { inScope }]) => inScope)
      .map(([key]) => key)
  );

  return {
    currentCounts,
    scopedTagNames,
  };
}

function applyCurrentCountThroughBoundContext(headingNode) {
  const { currentCounts, scopedTagNames } = this;

  const headingName = headingNode.tagName.toLowerCase();
  const headingNameList = ['h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'h6'];

  const nextMinorName = headingNameList
    .at(headingNameList.indexOf(headingName) + 1);

  if (nextMinorName) {
    const nextMinorCounts = currentCounts.get(nextMinorName);

    // - set the next minor heading-specific count to its
    //   default configuered `reset` value exactly once;
    // - after having applied the `reset`-default once, reset
    //   the next minor heading-specific count always to zero.
    nextMinorCounts.current = nextMinorCounts.reset;
    nextMinorCounts.reset = 0;
  }
  const counts = currentCounts.get(headingName);

  // - increment the heading-specific count
  //   of the currently processed heading-node.
  counts.current = counts.current + 1;

  if (scopedTagNames.has(headingName)) {

    // - compute and assign the correct counter-value
    //   according to both, the custom heading configuration
    //   and the currently processed node's heading-prescedence.

    headingNode.dataset.counter =
      headingNameList
        .slice(
          // - get all tag names of higher and equal
          //   heading-prescedence compared to the
          //   currently processed heading-node.
          0, headingNameList.indexOf(headingName) + 1
        )
        .reduce((counterList, name) =>
          counterList.concat(currentCounts.get(name).current), []
        )
        .join('.') + ".";
  }
}

/*export */function applyScopedHeadingCounts(config) {
  const {
    currentCounts,
    scopedTagNames,
  } =
    createCountContextObjects(config);

  const headingList = [
    ...document
      .querySelectorAll('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6')
  ];

  console.log({
    customConfig: config,
    scopedTagNames: [...scopedTagNames.values()],
    currentCounts: Object.fromEntries(currentCounts.entries()),
    headingList,
  });

  headingList
    .forEach(
      applyCurrentCountThroughBoundContext, {
        currentCounts, scopedTagNames,
      },
    );
}
// end ... counting-implementation or counting-module.


// another script-block's or module's scope
applyScopedHeadingCounts(customConfig);
body { margin: 0; }

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { margin: 4px 0; }

h1 { font-size: 1.6em; }
h2 { font-size: 1.4em; }
h3 { font-size: 1.25em; }
h4 { font-size: 1.1em; }
h5 { font-size: 1em; }
h6 { font-size: .9em; }

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  &::before { content: attr(data-counter) " "; }
}
.as-console-wrapper { left: auto!important; width: 50%; min-height: 100%; }
<h1>Heading 1</h1> <!-- <h1>Heading 1</h1>        -->
<h2>Heading 2</h2> <!-- <h2>1.1. Heading 2</h2>   -->
<h2>Heading 2</h2> <!-- <h2>1.2. Heading 2</h2>   -->
<h3>Heading 3</h3> <!-- <h3>1.2.1. Heading 3</h3> -->
<h3>Heading 3</h3> <!-- <h3>1.2.2. Heading 3</h3> -->
<h4>Heading 4</h4> <!-- <h4>Heading 4</h4>        -->
<h2>Heading 2</h2> <!-- <h2>1.3. Heading 2</h2>   -->
<h3>Heading 3</h3> <!-- <h3>1.3.1. Heading 3</h3> -->
<h4>Heading 4</h4> <!-- <h4>Heading 4</h4>        -->
<h5>Heading 5</h5> <!-- <h5>Heading 5</h5>        -->
<h6>Heading 6</h6> <!-- <h6>Heading 6</h6>        -->
<h6>Heading 6</h6> <!-- <h6>Heading 6</h6>        -->

<script>
  // config-file or inline-config

  const customConfig = {
    h1: { inScope: false },
    h4: { inScope: false },
    h5: { inScope: false },
    h6: { inScope: false },
  }
  /* ... same as ... */

  // const customConfig = {
  //   h1: { counter: 1, inScope: false },
  //   h2: { counter: 1, inScope: true },
  //   h3: { counter: 1, inScope: true },
  //   h4: { counter: 1, inScope: false },
  //   h5: { counter: 1, inScope: false },
  //   h6: { counter: 1, inScope: false },
  // }
</script>

<!--
<script>
  applyScopedHeadingCounts(customConfig);
</script>
//-->



2nd example code
The OP's usage of ...

default expected heading-scopes (all counters visible)
and some custom configured counter base-values different from 1 ...



// begin ... counting-implementation or counting-module.

function createCountContextObjects(config) {
  const headingDefault = {
    counter: 1,
    inScope: true,
  };
  const { h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 } = (config || {});

  const configEntries = Object
    .entries({
      h1: { ...headingDefault, ...(h1 || {}) },
      h2: { ...headingDefault, ...(h2 || {}) },
      h3: { ...headingDefault, ...(h3 || {}) },
      h4: { ...headingDefault, ...(h4 || {}) },
      h5: { ...headingDefault, ...(h5 || {}) },
      h6: { ...headingDefault, ...(h6 || {}) },
    });

  const currentCounts = new Map(
    configEntries
      .map(([key, { counter }]) => {

        counter = parseInt(counter, 10);
        counter = Number.isFinite(counter) ? (counter - 1) : 0;

        return [key, { reset: counter, current: counter }]
      })
  );
  const scopedTagNames = new Set(
    configEntries 
      .filter(([_, { inScope }]) => inScope)
      .map(([key]) => key)
  );

  return {
    currentCounts,
    scopedTagNames,
  };
}

function applyCurrentCountThroughBoundContext(headingNode) {
  const { currentCounts, scopedTagNames } = this;

  const headingName = headingNode.tagName.toLowerCase();
  const headingNameList = ['h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'h6'];

  const nextMinorName = headingNameList
    .at(headingNameList.indexOf(headingName) + 1);

  if (nextMinorName) {
    const nextMinorCounts = currentCounts.get(nextMinorName);

    // - set the next minor heading-specific count to its
    //   default configuered `reset` value exactly once;
    // - after having applied the `reset`-default once, reset
    //   the next minor heading-specific count always to zero.
    nextMinorCounts.current = nextMinorCounts.reset;
    nextMinorCounts.reset = 0;
  }
  const counts = currentCounts.get(headingName);

  // - increment the heading-specific count
  //   of the currently processed heading-node.
  counts.current = counts.current + 1;

  if (scopedTagNames.has(headingName)) {

    // - compute and assign the correct counter-value
    //   according to both, the custom heading configuration
    //   and the currently processed node's heading-prescedence.

    headingNode.dataset.counter =
      headingNameList
        .slice(
          // - get all tag names of higher and equal
          //   heading-prescedence compared to the
          //   currently processed heading-node.
          0, headingNameList.indexOf(headingName) + 1
        )
        .reduce((counterList, name) =>
          counterList.concat(currentCounts.get(name).current), []
        )
        .join('.') + ".";
  }
}

/*export */function applyScopedHeadingCounts(config) {
  const {
    currentCounts,
    scopedTagNames,
  } =
    createCountContextObjects(config);

  const headingList = [
    ...document
      .querySelectorAll('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6')
  ];

  console.log({
    customConfig: config,
    scopedTagNames: [...scopedTagNames.values()],
    currentCounts: Object.fromEntries(currentCounts.entries()),
    headingList,
  });

  headingList
    .forEach(
      applyCurrentCountThroughBoundContext, {
        currentCounts, scopedTagNames,
      },
    );
}
// end ... counting-implementation or counting-module.


// another script-block's or module's scope
applyScopedHeadingCounts(customConfig);
body { margin: 0; }

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { margin: 4px 0; }

h1 { font-size: 1.6em; }
h2 { font-size: 1.4em; }
h3 { font-size: 1.25em; }
h4 { font-size: 1.1em; }
h5 { font-size: 1em; }
h6 { font-size: .9em; }

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  &::before { content: attr(data-counter) " "; }
}
.as-console-wrapper { left: auto!important; width: 50%; min-height: 100%; }
<h1>Heading 1</h1> <!-- <h1>12. Heading 1</h1>            -->
<h2>Heading 2</h2> <!-- <h2>12.1. Heading 2</h2>          -->
<h3>Heading 3</h3> <!-- <h3>12.1.5. Heading 3</h3>        -->
<h4>Heading 4</h4> <!-- <h4>12.1.5.8. Heading 4</h4>      -->
<h5>Heading 5</h5> <!-- <h5>12.1.5.8.1. Heading 5</h5>    -->
<h6>Heading 6</h6> <!-- <h6>12.1.5.8.1.10. Heading 6</h6> -->
<h6>Heading 6</h6> <!-- <h6>12.1.5.8.1.11. Heading 6</h6> -->
<h3>Heading 3</h3> <!-- <h3>12.1.6. Heading 3</h3>        -->
<h4>Heading 4</h4> <!-- <h4>12.1.6.1. Heading 4</h4>      -->
<h5>Heading 5</h5> <!-- <h5>12.1.6.1.1. Heading 5</h5>    -->
<h6>Heading 6</h6> <!-- <h6>12.1.6.1.1.1. Heading 6</h6>  -->
<h6>Heading 6</h6> <!-- <h6>12.1.6.1.1.2. Heading 6</h6>  -->

<script>
  // config-file or inline-config

  const customConfig = {
    h1: { counter: 12 },
    h3: { counter: 5 },
    h4: { counter: 8 },
    h6: { counter: 10 },
  }
  /* ... same as ... */

  // const customConfig = {
  //   h1: { counter: 12, inScope: true },
  //   h2: { counter: 1, inScope: true },
  //   h3: { counter: 5, inScope: true },
  //   h4: { counter: 8, inScope: true },
  //   h5: { counter: 1, inScope: true },
  //   h6: { counter: 10, inScope: true },
  // }
</script>

<!--
<script>
  applyScopedHeadingCounts(customConfig);
</script>
//-->



3rd example code
One of the far above's "CSS-only" heading-markups with ...

default expected heading-scopes (all counters visible)
and some custom configured counter base-values different from 1 ...



// begin ... counting-implementation or counting-module.

function createCountContextObjects(config) {
  const headingDefault = {
    counter: 1,
    inScope: true,
  };
  const { h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 } = (config || {});

  const configEntries = Object
    .entries({
      h1: { ...headingDefault, ...(h1 || {}) },
      h2: { ...headingDefault, ...(h2 || {}) },
      h3: { ...headingDefault, ...(h3 || {}) },
      h4: { ...headingDefault, ...(h4 || {}) },
      h5: { ...headingDefault, ...(h5 || {}) },
      h6: { ...headingDefault, ...(h6 || {}) },
    });

  const currentCounts = new Map(
    configEntries
      .map(([key, { counter }]) => {

        counter = parseInt(counter, 10);
        counter = Number.isFinite(counter) ? (counter - 1) : 0;

        return [key, { reset: counter, current: counter }]
      })
  );
  const scopedTagNames = new Set(
    configEntries 
      .filter(([_, { inScope }]) => inScope)
      .map(([key]) => key)
  );

  return {
    currentCounts,
    scopedTagNames,
  };
}

function applyCurrentCountThroughBoundContext(headingNode) {
  const { currentCounts, scopedTagNames } = this;

  const headingName = headingNode.tagName.toLowerCase();
  const headingNameList = ['h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'h6'];

  const nextMinorName = headingNameList
    .at(headingNameList.indexOf(headingName) + 1);

  if (nextMinorName) {
    const nextMinorCounts = currentCounts.get(nextMinorName);

    // - set the next minor heading-specific count to its
    //   default configuered `reset` value exactly once;
    // - after having applied the `reset`-default once, reset
    //   the next minor heading-specific count always to zero.
    nextMinorCounts.current = nextMinorCounts.reset;
    nextMinorCounts.reset = 0;
  }
  const counts = currentCounts.get(headingName);

  // - increment the heading-specific count
  //   of the currently processed heading-node.
  counts.current = counts.current + 1;

  if (scopedTagNames.has(headingName)) {

    // - compute and assign the correct counter-value
    //   according to both, the custom heading configuration
    //   and the currently processed node's heading-prescedence.

    headingNode.dataset.counter =
      headingNameList
        .slice(
          // - get all tag names of higher and equal
          //   heading-prescedence compared to the
          //   currently processed heading-node.
          0, headingNameList.indexOf(headingName) + 1
        )
        .reduce((counterList, name) =>
          counterList.concat(currentCounts.get(name).current), []
        )
        .join('.') + ".";
  }
}

/*export */function applyScopedHeadingCounts(config) {
  const {
    currentCounts,
    scopedTagNames,
  } =
    createCountContextObjects(config);

  const headingList = [
    ...document
      .querySelectorAll('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6')
  ];

  console.log({
    customConfig: config,
    scopedTagNames: [...scopedTagNames.values()],
    currentCounts: Object.fromEntries(currentCounts.entries()),
    headingList,
  });

  headingList
    .forEach(
      applyCurrentCountThroughBoundContext, {
        currentCounts, scopedTagNames,
      },
    );
}
// end ... counting-implementation or counting-module.


// another script-block's or module's scope
applyScopedHeadingCounts(customConfig);
body { margin: 0; }

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { margin: 4px 0; }

h1 { font-size: 1.6em; }
h2 { font-size: 1.4em; }
h3 { font-size: 1.25em; }
h4 { font-size: 1.1em; }
h5 { font-size: 1em; }
h6 { font-size: .9em; }

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  &::before { content: attr(data-counter) " "; }
}
.as-console-wrapper { left: auto!important; width: 50%; min-height: 100%; }
<h1>Heading-1</h1>

  <h2>Heading-2</h2>

    <h3>Heading-3</h3>
    <h3>Heading-3</h3>
    
      <h4>Heading-4</h4>
      <h4>Heading-4</h4>

  <h2>Heading-2</h2>

    <h3>Heading-3</h3>
    <h3>Heading-3</h3>

      <h4>Heading-4</h4>

  <h2>Heading-2</h2>

    <h3>Heading-3</h3>

      <h4>Heading-4</h4>

        <h5>Heading-5</h5>

          <h6>Heading-6</h6>
          <h6>Heading-6</h6>


<h1>Heading-1</h1>

  <h2>Heading-2</h2>
  <h2>Heading-2</h2>

    <h3>Heading-3</h3>
    <h3>Heading-3</h3>

      <h4>Heading-4</h4>

  <h2>Heading-2</h2>

    <h3>Heading-3</h3>

      <h4>Heading-4</h4>

        <h5>Heading-5</h5>

          <h6>Heading-6</h6>
          <h6>Heading-6</h6>


<h1>Heading-1</h1>


<script>
  // config-file or inline-config

  const customConfig = {
    h1: { counter: 10 },
    h2: { counter: 4 },
    h3: { counter: 7 },
  }
</script>

<!--
<script>
  applyScopedHeadingCounts(customConfig);
</script>
//-->




Hi @Peter Seliger! Thanks for that code, and though it works amazingly as a CSS solution, this JS code will be part of a bigger JS first product, so on compile time it will statically be embedded into the DOM. If you have a JS only version of yours I'd love to see it!

@markb ... I updated my answer according to your original request. The new edit focuses on a JS driven solution.

! Wow - that’s comprehensive and appreciative for breaking down the different scenarios. I can definitely work with this and integrate it nicely into the code base. Both the JS and CSS solutions work great as i’m sure there will be others out there needing options for both

You actually don't need JS for this. This can be achieved just with CSS if you are fine with the browser support (which is 88.75% - for counter-set - at the time of writing: caniuse.com), by using counter-reset, counter-set, counter-increment, ::before and content.


body {
  counter-reset: h1;
}

h1 {
  counter-reset: h2;
}

h2 {
  counter-reset: h3;
}

h3 {
  counter-reset: h4;
}

h4 {
  counter-reset: h5;
}

h5 {
  counter-reset: h6;
}

h1::before {
  counter-increment: h1;
  content: counter(h1) ". ";
}

h2::before {
  counter-increment: h2;
  content: counter(h1) "." counter(h2) ". ";
}

h3::before {
  counter-increment: h3;
  content: counter(h1) "." counter(h2) "." counter(h3) ". ";
}

h4::before {
  counter-increment: h4;
  content: counter(h1) "." counter(h2) "." counter(h3) "." counter(h4) ". ";
}

h5::before {
  counter-increment: h5;
  content: counter(h1) "." counter(h2) "."counter(h3) "."counter(h4) "."counter(h5) ". ";
}

h6::before {
  counter-increment: h6;
  content: counter(h1) "." counter(h2) "."counter(h3) "."counter(h4) "."counter(h5) "."counter(h6) ". ";
}
<h1>Heading 1</h1>
<h2>Heading 2</h2>
<h2>Heading 2</h2>
<h3>Heading 3</h3>
<h3>Heading 3</h3>
<h4>Heading 4</h4>
<h2>Heading 2</h2>
<h3>Heading 3</h3>
<h4>Heading 4</h4>
<h5>Heading 5</h5>
<h6>Heading 6</h6>
<h6>Heading 6</h6>



To start at a different number you would use counter-set:


body {
  counter-set: h1 5;
}

h1 {
  counter-reset: h2;
}

h2 {
  counter-reset: h3;
}

h3 {
  counter-reset: h4;
}

h4 {
  counter-reset: h5;
}

h5 {
  counter-reset: h6;
}

h1::before {
  counter-increment: h1;
  content: counter(h1) ". ";
}

h2::before {
  counter-increment: h2;
  content: counter(h1) "." counter(h2) ". ";
}

h3::before {
  counter-increment: h3;
  content: counter(h1) "." counter(h2) "." counter(h3) ". ";
}

h4::before {
  counter-increment: h4;
  content: counter(h1) "." counter(h2) "." counter(h3) "." counter(h4) ". ";
}

h5::before {
  counter-increment: h5;
  content: counter(h1) "." counter(h2) "."counter(h3) "."counter(h4) "."counter(h5) ". ";
}

h6::before {
  counter-increment: h6;
  content: counter(h1) "." counter(h2) "."counter(h3) "."counter(h4) "."counter(h5) "."counter(h6) ". ";
}
<h1>Heading 1</h1>
<h2>Heading 2</h2>
<h2>Heading 2</h2>
<h3>Heading 3</h3>
<h3>Heading 3</h3>
<h4>Heading 4</h4>
<h2>Heading 2</h2>
<h3>Heading 3</h3>
<h4>Heading 4</h4>
<h5>Heading 5</h5>
<h6>Heading 6</h6>
<h6>Heading 6</h6>



And whether or not to prefix your headings with the numberings can be controlled using content, which could be done using a distinct class (how depends on the use-case):


body {
  counter-set: h1 5;
}

h1 {
  counter-reset: h2;
}

h2 {
  counter-reset: h3;
}

h3 {
  counter-reset: h4;
}

h4 {
  counter-reset: h5;
}

h5 {
  counter-reset: h6;
}

h1::before {
  counter-increment: h1;
  content: "";
}

h2::before {
  counter-increment: h2;
  content: counter(h1) "." counter(h2) ". ";
}

h3::before {
  counter-increment: h3;
  content: counter(h1) "." counter(h2) "." counter(h3) ". ";
}

h4::before {
  counter-increment: h4;
  content: "";
}

h5::before {
  counter-increment: h5;
  content: "";
}

h6::before {
  counter-increment: h6;
  content: "";
}
<h1>Heading 1</h1>
<h2>Heading 2</h2>
<h2>Heading 2</h2>
<h3>Heading 3</h3>
<h3>Heading 3</h3>
<h4>Heading 4</h4>
<h2>Heading 2</h2>
<h3>Heading 3</h3>
<h4>Heading 4</h4>
<h5>Heading 5</h5>
<h6>Heading 6</h6>
<h6>Heading 6</h6>



If you don't want to include a CSS file you could also create the CSS programmatically in JS. Here a - not yet fully tested - example:


let sheet = new CSSStyleSheet();

let startNumbers = [3];
let applyNumbering = [false, true, true, true];
let maxHNumber = 6;


function createCounterReset(from, to) {
  let result = [];
  for (let i = from; i <= to; i++) {
    result.push(`h${i}`);
  }
  if (result.length == 0) {
    return ""
  }
  return `counter-reset: ${result.join(' ')};`;
}

function createCounter(to) {
  let result = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < to; i++) {
    result.push(`counter(h${i+1})`);
  }
  return result.join(' "." ') + ' ". "';
}

let style = [];
style.push('body {');
if (startNumbers.length > 0) {
  style.push('counter-set: ' + startNumbers.map((value, idx) => `h${idx+1} ${value-1}`).join(' ')) + ';'
}
style.push('}');


for (let i = 0; i < maxHNumber; i++) {
  style.push(`h${i+1} {
    ${createCounterReset(i+2, maxHNumber)}
    counter-increment: h${i+1};
    }`);

  if (applyNumbering[i]) {
    style.push(`h${i+1}::before {
      content: ${createCounter(i+1)};
    }`);
  }
}

sheet.replaceSync(style.join("\n"));
document.adoptedStyleSheets = [sheet];
<h1>Heading 1</h1>
<h2>Heading 2</h2>
<h2>Heading 2</h2>
<h3>Heading 3</h3>
<h3>Heading 3</h3>
<h4>Heading 4</h4>
<h2>Heading 2</h2>
<h3>Heading 3</h3>
<h4>Heading 4</h4>
<h5>Heading 5</h5>
<h6>Heading 6</h6>
<h6>Heading 6</h6>




Hi @t.niese! Thanks for that code, and for working on both versions (all headings and the scoped headings). But this JS plugin will be part of a bigger JS only framework so the intention is to have it JS only.

@markb Why is using CSS a problem in that case? You only want to have a .js file to be included?  If so is it an option to programmatically create the CSS? I mean, yes, it would for sure be possible to do that with JS, but using CSS is much more maintainable (e.g., in case the HTML is changed dynamically).

@markb Added an example of how you could create the CSS programmatically in JS.

I think that's easier to implement the looping with a stack, rather than with a flat object:


const level = 6;
const headingNumbers = {h1: 12, h2: 1, h3: 5, h4: 8, h5: 1, h6: 10};

const headers = [...document.querySelectorAll(Array.from({length: level}, (_, i) => 'h' + (i + 1)).join(','))];

let prevLevel = 0;
const stack = [];
for(const header of headers){
  const level = +header.tagName.match(/\d+/)[0];
  if(level > prevLevel) {
    const tag = header.tagName.toLowerCase();
    stack.push(headingNumbers[tag] ?? 1);
    delete headingNumbers[tag];
  } else {
    stack.splice(level, stack.length);
    stack[stack.length - 1]++;
  }
  header.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', `<span>${stack.join('.')}</span>&nbsp;`);
  prevLevel = level;
}
<h1>Heading 1</h1>
<h2>Heading 2</h2>
<h2>Heading 2</h2>
<h3>Heading 3</h3>
<h3>Heading 3</h3>
<h4>Heading 4</h4>
<h2>Heading 2</h2>
<h3>Heading 3</h3>
<h4>Heading 4</h4>
<h5>Heading 5</h5>
<h6>Heading 6</h6>
<h6>Heading 6</h6>
<h1>Heading 1</h1>
<h2>Heading 2</h2>
<h2>Heading 2</h2>
<h3>Heading 3</h3>
<h3>Heading 3</h3>
<h4>Heading 4</h4>
<h2>Heading 2</h2>
<h3>Heading 3</h3>
<h4>Heading 4</h4>
<h5>Heading 5</h5>
<h6>Heading 6</h6>
<h6>Heading 6</h6>




Very interesting and clever! One thing is the last code block I have in the original question where there is scoping of the heading tags to add numbers to. Would your version be adaptable to implementing that too?

@markb, yes, it's set by const level = 6;

I understand that, but I updated that section to be this:
const levelsRange = Array.from(
 { length: options.levels.finish - options.levels.start + 1 },
 (_, i) => 'h' + (i + options.levels.start)
).join(',');

But the numbering does not prefix with the previous headings numbers.
